# Cisco ASA - My NAT is forcing traffic out the wrong interface!

Tags: cisco-asa

Cisco ASA 5508, 9.6.3 code. I have 2 outside interfaces `BACKUP` and `PRIMARY` and a `INSIDE` interface. For some reason the NAT sends traffic out the BACKUP interface even when BACKUP is down!

[image]

[**Edit** I have isolated the issue and made this question simpler]

I have found that **if** you're using **twice NAT** that has a **destination**, the ASA will **route the packet based on the NAT** and completely ignore the routing table. Here is the relavant config.

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 nameif PRIMARY
 security-level 0
 ip address 22.22.22.22 255.255.255.240
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 nameif INSIDE
 security-level 100
 ip address 172.16.1.10 255.255.255.0
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 nameif BACKUP
 security-level 0
 ip address 33.33.33.33 255.255.255.0

route OUTSIDE 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 22.22.22.23 1

object network OBJ-55.55.55.55
 host 55.55.55.55
object service OBJ-HTTP
 service tcp destination eq 80
nat (INSIDE,BACKUP) source static any interface destination static OBJ-55.55.55.55 OBJ-55.55.55.55 
nat (INSIDE,PRIMARY) source static any interface destination static OBJ-55.55.55.55 OBJ-55.55.55.55 
nat (INSIDE,any) source static any any service OBJ-HTTP OBJ-HTTP no-proxy-arp
```

My goal is to NAT traffic going to 55.55.55.55 to the Interface, and nonat everything else that's on port 80.

When I do this config and try a packet trace, we can see it takes the wrong path.

```
ASA-DEV# packet-tracer input INSIDE tcp 172.16.1.99 2222 55.55.55.55 80

Phase: 1
Type: CAPTURE
Subtype:
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:
MAC Access list

Phase: 2
Type: ACCESS-LIST
Subtype:
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Implicit Rule
Additional Information:
MAC Access list

Phase: 3
Type: UN-NAT
Subtype: static
Result: ALLOW
Config:
nat (INSIDE,BACKUP) source static any interface destination static OBJ-55.55.55.55 OBJ-55.55.55.55
Additional Information:
NAT divert to egress interface BACKUP-INTERNET-TEST
Untranslate 55.55.55.55/80 to 55.55.55.55/80

Phase: 4
Type: ACCESS-LIST
Subtype: log
Result: ALLOW
Config:
access-group ACL-INSIDE-IN in interface INSIDE
access-list ACL-INSIDE-IN extended permit ip any host 55.55.55.55
Additional Information:

Phase: 5
Type: NAT
Subtype:
Result: ALLOW
Config:
nat (INSIDE,BACKUP) source static any interface destination static OBJ-55.55.55.55 OBJ-55.55.55.55
Additional Information:
Static translate 172.16.1.99/2222 to 192.168.79.1/2222

Phase: 6
Type: NAT
Subtype: per-session
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:

Phase: 7
Type: IP-OPTIONS
Subtype:
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:

Phase: 8
Type: INSPECT
Subtype: inspect-http
Result: ALLOW
Config:
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect http PMAP-HTTP-INSPECT
service-policy global_policy global
Additional Information:

Phase: 9
Type: NAT
Subtype: rpf-check
Result: ALLOW
Config:
nat (INSIDE,BACKUP) source static any interface destination static OBJ-55.55.55.55 OBJ-55.55.55.55
Additional Information:

Phase: 10
Type: NAT
Subtype: per-session
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:

Phase: 11
Type: IP-OPTIONS
Subtype:
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:

Phase: 12
Type: FLOW-CREATION
Subtype:
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:
New flow created with id 1404251, packet dispatched to next module

Result:
input-interface: INSIDE
input-status: up
input-line-status: up
output-interface: BACKUP
output-status: down
output-line-status: down
Action: allow
```

Some more show commands:

```
ASA-DEV(config)# sh route

Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2, V - VPN
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, + - replicated route
Gateway of last resort is 208.69.250.17 to network 0.0.0.0

S*       0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 [1/0] via 22.22.22.23, OUTSIDE
C        172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0 is directly connected, INSIDE

ASA-DEV(config)# sho int ip brie
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0         22.22.22.22     YES CONFIG up                    up
GigabitEthernet0/1         172.16.1.10     YES CONFIG up                    up
GigabitEthernet0/2         33.33.33.33     YES manual down                  down
GigabitEthernet0/3         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
GigabitEthernet0/4         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
GigabitEthernet0/5         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
```

As you can see my routing table is bare bones and my BACKUP interface (G0/2) isn't even up. SO WHY ON EARTH IS THE NAT TRYING TO ROUTE OUT THE BACKUP INTERFACE!?

Comment: What you are not giving us are the routing commands. NAT simply translates IP addresses in packets, it does not route the packets. You should edit your question to include the entire configuration.

Comment: Check your routing table. NAT does not 'add' routes. Are you redistributing it via some protocol

Comment: It's not routing based on NAT. Packets are routed based on the destination address. Another NAT could change the original source address so that the resulting destination address for replies will be through a non-default interface. You really need to provide a much better network description, and network device models with full configurations.

Comment: Ron, I have duplicated the exact config above in 3 ASAs now with different version and hardware. This should be enough code for you to easily try it in a lab yourself. Just make a BACKUP interface and try the NAT statement I wrote and you'll see that in fact NAT is doing routing here.

Comment: Routing happens to each packet, individually, regardless of any other packets, and it is based on the destination address on the packet. If you have a second NAT, that could be changing a source address that ends up as a destination address on replies. NAT only changes addresses in a packet, it doesn't route packets.

Comment: @RonMaupin the config I posted is my entire NAT table and routing table. There is no other NAT statements or routes at all. This is a odd case that with these exact conditions, the ASA does routing solely based on the NAT and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very specific part of the ASA packet processing that many don't know about called **NAT Divert Check**

[Simply explained here](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11903326/cisco-asa-traffic-flow-destination-nat):

> The NAT divert check (which is what overrides the routing table) is
>   checking to see if there is any NAT rule that specifies destination
>   address translation for an inbound packet arriving on an interface.
>
> If there is no rule that explicitly specifies how to translate that packet's destination IP address, then the global routing table is
>   consulted to determine the egress interface.
>
> If there is a rule that explicitly specifies how to translate the packets destination IP address, then the NAT rule "pulls" the packet
>   to the other interface in the translation and the global routing table
>   is effectively bypassed.

Cisco has stated these NAT rules are intended to override the routing table.

You can use an EEM script as a workaround to keep your NAT statements and still make it work. The script relies on IP SLA to track for a syslog message the IP SLA failure would trigger, then adds or removes your NAT when that happens.
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/118049-config-eem-00.html